# Result from plot(cpt.mean) is NULL

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

When plotting the results of a changepoint analysis using the `changepoint` package the result is NULL. The plot is visible is the viewer but it is not an object. As a result, when I try to add it to 3 other plots (ggplots to be exact) using `gridExtra::grid.arrange`, it's not visible. Any suggestions?

Sample code:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(date_rec = seq(as.Date("2014-01-01"),as.Date("2015-12-31"), by=1),
                 number = sample(c(1:10),size = 730, replace=TRUE))

df_ts <-  ts(df$number, frequency=12, start=c(2014,1), end=c(2015,12))
df_ts

monthly_data <- aggregate(number ~ year(date_rec) + month(date_rec), data = df, FUN = sum)

# Create a time series object
df_ts <- ts(monthly_data$number, frequency = 12, start = c(2014, 1))

cpt_mean <- cpt.mean(df_ts, method = "AMOC", penalty = "AIC")
p_changepoint <- plot(cpt_mean)
p_changepoint
```

Comment: That’s kind of expected: see [the documentation of the `plot()` generic function](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/plot.html): it has no documented return value. You can use [`grid.grab()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grid/html/grid.grab.html) to store the current plot as a grid compatible object.

Comment: Thanks! Although I couldn't get your suggestion to work, it put me on the right track to get the plot converted to a ggplot object

Answer (score 0):

It took some searching, but I found a way to convert the plot to a ggplot using the following code:

```
as.ggplot(function() plot(cpt.mean(df_ts, method = "AMOC", penalty = "AIC")))
```